# document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML getting error for angular 13

Tags: angular, angular13

Help to resolve this. Want to contact the data I tried all possible ways

(method) Document.getElementById(elementId: string): HTMLElement | null

Returns a reference to the first object with the specified value of the ID attribute.

*@param* `elementId` — String that specifies the ID value.

Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

Comment: BTW, why do you need to `getElementById` in an Angular project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementById('msg')` will return the element that has the id "msg" **if it exists**. But it might not exist. This is why the response is not a `HTMLElement` but a `HTMLElement | null`.

This means that you have to handle the `null` case. This is the meaning of the error message `Object is possibly 'null'`.

If you know that the element always exists, you can assert that it is not `null`, like this:

```js
document.getElementById('msg')!.innerHTML
                              ^
```

Or, if it can be `null`, you can use a `if/else` statement

```js
const element = document.getElementById('msg')
if (element) {
  const innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
  [...]
} else {
  [...]
}
```

That would solve the problem but I have to add that you normally never have to get elements with `document.getElementById` in Angular. This would "work" but is not the correct way of doing it.

It would be better to use the `ViewChild` syntax (see [doc](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)).

In html, mark the targeted element with a name, like this :

```html
<div id="msg" #msgElement>
   [...]      ^^^^^^^^^^^
</div>
```

And, on TypeScript side :

```js
@ViewChild('msgElement')
msgElement?: HTMLElement
```

Beware, the `ViewChild` is initiated only after the `AfterViewInit()` method of the Angular lifecycle. If you try to call it too soon, like in the `constructor` or `OnInit()`, you will get `undefined`